# Infinite Scroll with Wordpress version 3.8

Tags: jquery, wordpress, infinite-scroll

I'm looking for hours to fix the [Infinite Scroll](http://wordpress.org/plugins/infinite-scroll/) on my WordPress website. It looks so easy to implement and I've done it before, but apparently I'm doing something wrong now or the plugin is not compatible with WordPress 3.8.

I already fixed the same infinite scroll a while ago on another website with WordPress version 3.5.1. After comparing both WordPress installations and themes I still can't fix it.

What am I doing wrong?

**Things I did so far:**

- Disabled other plugins to look if there are any conflicts
- Reinstalled the plugin many times
- Add `window.onload = function()` around the script in footer.php
  (infinite-scroll/templates/footer.php) to trigger the script after pageload.
- Changed `singular()` to `single()` in infinite-scroll.php line 307, to load the JavaScript on custom page templates.

I want to use the infinite scroll on a custom page template.

**The WordPress pagination output on my page is:**

```
<div class="pagination">
  <div class="next">
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/products/?page_id=22&paged=2" >Next page</a>                                             
  </div>
</div>
```

**The selectors in the admin panel are:**

- Content Selector: `#products`
- Navigation selector: `.pagination`
- Next selector: `.pagination .next a`
- Item selector: `#products article`

**The index.php content:**

```
<section id="products" class="products fullwidth first">                                    
<?php                           
  if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
  elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
  else { $paged = 1; }

   $args= array (
   'post_type' => 'products', 
   'paged' => $paged
   );

   query_posts( $args ); ?>
   <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

   <article class="product item">

     [article content]

   </article>

   <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php else : ?>
   <?php endif; ?>

   <div class="pagination">
       <div class="next">
           <?php echo get_next_posts_link(); ?>
       </div>
    </div>

   <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
</section>
```

**The scripts generated by the plugin in the footer** (in this order):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var infinite_scroll = "{\"loading\":{\"msgText\":\"<em>Loading...<\\\/em>\",\"finishedMsg\":\"<em>No additional posts.<\\\/em>\",\"img\":\"http:\\\/\\\/localhost:8080\\\/products\\\/wp-content\\\/plugins\\\/infinite-scroll\\\/img\\\/ajax-loader.gif\"},\"nextSelector\":\".pagination .next a\",\"navSelector\":\".pagination\",\"itemSelector\":\"#products article\",\"contentSelector\":\"#products\",\"debug\":false,\"behavior\":\"\",\"callback\":\"\"}";
/* ]]> */
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost:8080/products/wp-content/plugins/infinite-scroll/js/front-end/jquery.infinitescroll.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
// Because the <code>wp_localize_script</code> method makes everything a string
    infinite_scroll = jQuery.parseJSON(infinite_scroll);
    jQuery( infinite_scroll.contentSelector ).infinitescroll( infinite_scroll, function(newElements, data, url) { eval(infinite_scroll.callback); });
};
</script>
```